# Why is TypeScript Not Checking the Type of Dynamic Key Object Fields

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Why does TypeScript accept the definition of `seta` when it does not return objects of type `A`?

```
type A = {
    a: '123',
    b: '456'
}

// Returns copy of obj with obj[k] = '933'
function seta<K extends keyof A>(k: K, obj: A): A {
    return {
        ...obj,
        [k]: '933'
    }
}

const w: A = seta('a', {
    a: '123',
    b: '456'
})

// now w = {a: '933', b: '456'}
```

https://tsplay.dev/wEGX4m

Comment: Interesting, looks like TypeScript is not smart enough to handle the case when you override the return value keys with that dynamic key `k`. At first sight it looks like a bug that should be reported.

Comment: in spread, typescript infers types based on known types, i.e. typeof obj in this case. any 'dynamic' keys would be ignored. this might be changed in future version though.

Comment: I downvoted this question because the title assumes an erroneous understanding and is thus misleading. Fix it so that it is specific and helpful in SO searches and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @Inigo definitely!  Hopefully mentioning that the issue affects type checking dynamic keys will make this easier to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug or limitation in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#37103](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37103) (labeled a bug) or [microsoft/TypeScript#32236](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32236) (labeled "needs investigation").

When you [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#spread_properties) properties into an object literal and then add a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names), it seems that TypeScript will completely ignore the computed property unless the computed key is of a single, specific, [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) (not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of literals, and not a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a string literal):

```
function testing<K extends "a" | "b">(a: "a", x: string, y: "a" | "b", z: K) {
    const someObject = { a: "v" } // { a: string }
    const objA = { ...someObject, [a]: 0 } // { a: number } 
    const objX = { ...someObject, [x]: 0 } // { a: string } 
    const objY = { ...someObject, [y]: 0 } // { a: string } 
    const objZ = { ...someObject, [z]: 0 } // { a: string } 
}
```

Computed property keys in general are a bit problematic in TypeScript, even without spreading, as they tend to get widened all the way to `string`, losing information you might care about (see another bug at [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948)):

```
function testing2<K extends "a" | "b">(a: "a", x: string, y: "a" | "b", z: K) {
    const objA = { [a]: 0 } // { a: number } 
    const objX = { [x]: 0 } // { [x: string]: number; } ‍♂️
    const objY = { [y]: 0 } // { [x: string]: number; } ‍♂️
    const objZ = { [z]: 0 } // { [x: string]: number; } ‍♂️
}
```

So that's the problem you're having here.

---

I don't know what to say other than "tread lightly around computed properties".  You can kind of work around it by defining your own function that produces a more "correct" version of what a computed property would be:

```
function kv<K extends PropertyKey, V>(k: K, v: V) {
    return { [k]: v } as { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: V } }[K]
}

const k = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b";

const obj = kv(k, Math.random());
/* const obj: {
    a: number;
} | {
    b: number;
} */
```

You can see that a union of keys produces a union of objects.  But if the key is generic then the compiler leaves that unevaluated and spread with generics tends to be represented as an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), which is often acceptable but not when keys overlap.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#32022](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32022) for that issue):

```
function setA2<K extends keyof A>(k: K, obj: A): A {
    return {
        ...obj,
        ...kv(k, '933')
    } 
    /* const ret1: A & { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: string; }; }[K] */ // no error
}
```

So you'd have to widen `k` from `K` to `keyof A` before you got any warning:

```
function setA3<K extends keyof A>(k: K, obj: A): A {
    const kW: keyof A = k;
    return {
        ...obj,
        ...kv(kW, '933')
    }; // FINALLY AN ERROR
    // Type '{ a: string; b: "456"; } | { b: string; a: "123"; }' is not assignable to type 'A'.
}
```

So, hooray, I guess... you can spend a lot of effort to wrestle some type safety out of this function, but it's quite a pyrrhic victory (I [think](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Apyrrhic) that's a word).  So again, be careful around computed properties until and unless the relevant GitHub issues are fixed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-oCMBaoNKycjGTHdZyUTy+QLhWK-VK4XKpJHNazY4OItXPcYtcP+QkANzswB8G4B2XcAsASAITJAPB-5qJXet8oizvnA+xS4NRtXuHXAu3GP3x7PE8tsKDM5Rv2bq9sutYvlAb5bruh6ntkaYLEYghFHmWyFh4Xg+P4QQhDc0oSOEsDtugnZJCIUjijIirSooMgYBkWp4AAnCQZDigSGBkSkaRkZu2SdgA7hIBTIfUpQUGIFRjLwAA2EDkjJvDGAEAlSQhGZpO4oioQWOwAArDJACSgFYXg3AAaoEwRQFYNziFA5kAtInHJKkD6ZLgojspgbi9npUCrDZWq9gAigFaR6Vq5nsuwURZCmnbuAUACymDAAAFuSCSYC4EIBACFjauSjBQAA-FchxvGcfGdtKBRaUENypRlWU5c4eWhKEfHNAAVBKF74cRQ68hufEYicznoMoUFjVAPXNHM6aLFAWZPCQOnbEWjafGcFwNi2txPk89YVU23xQH8NlOeeIL2qqiIzhWaILu6R1ejdk6wj2CohjS90RoqDWYDcLIAve+qQSNo7euOHYDVOwZKqGDr0j95INXYINgyB8bPqaH1-jaM52sj-03IDogBCAWMvRDK747+l7-ojd3huTlINT8NPg7jiZQD62SpvMGmgmYMC5jY+abRh3i+DAVm4UzBHCZNUBcW5qtUZSNGURgFONfgLFkBUMgcegvX9SCZEEMJABkD7+YFMS4KF4VQJFb3GB+H5xXNbRYvwvC2EMIzwcLy2iTA62S2hOyeLL2HWbZSuwIRcCq4lADquDx1hZLuHxMjq2kmt69rcK0XRaMNe4mc3MxrFNKb25YgAYgAkgAcjAAAyPc2jAndQAAogASqPUKj+KWIACrgNAeB0+B27KLsqi7B+JbIsoK7bhW8gb-ieABW4gciD5gj6MY-CYNQckrUHoCQPgMB4OS6hAA)

Answer (score 1):

It's accepted because if you hover on `[k]: '933',` it says

> (parameter) k: K extends keyof A

Which means you're returning a property that's extended from the return type, which is allowed.

When you declare that an object must be of an interface, you are saying that it must have at least those properties, not only those properties.

Comment: Also, though it's true that `K` doesn't have to be `'a'` or `'b'`, it can be, and if it is, then the object returned won't be of type `A`.

Comment: Like I said "you're returning a property that's extended from the return type, which is allowed.", When you declare it like that you're saying it must be of type A or extend type A.

Comment: But `seta` can return `{a: '933', b: '456'}`, which is definitely not of type `A`.

Comment: It's also not assignable to `interface B extends A {}` because `a` must be `'123'` (though that shouldn't matter because the function was declared as returning type `A`)

Comment: I don’t see how this answers the question, exactly.  What do you mean by “extended from the return type”?  The `Y extends X` constraint means that `Y` must be assignable to `X`, not the other way around.